# Debian chroot blocking PTTYs on host

Tags: tty, chroot, urxvt

I've created a Debian-based chroot environment using `debootstrap` under Arch Linux, and fill it with life like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

mount -t proc proc $CHROOT/proc
mount -t devpts devpts $CHROOT/dev/pts

chroot $CHROOT /bin/bash --login -c "/etc/init.d/ssh start"
```

The problem is that after executing the script above, I'm not able to open new terminals on the host system anymore:

```
urxvt: can't initialize pseudo-tty, aborting.
```

Shutting down the `chroot` (stopping `sshd`, unmounting proc and dev/pts) does not bring back new terminals on the host.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /dev/pts` before and after. Stab in the dark: is `mount --bind /dev/pts $CHROOT/dev/pts` any better? You'll probably save a lot of effort by using [schroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Schroot&redirect=no) instead of building your own.

Comment: `mount --bind` did the trick, thanks! ;)
Outputs of `ls -l /dev/pts` did not differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `mount -t devpts devpts $CHROOT/dev/pts`, this mounts a separate instance of the devpts filesystem in the chroot. An alternative way of making devpts available in the chroot is to use a bind mount, which makes the same instance of the filesystem available at a new location. Bind mounts are like making a hard link, only for mount points instead of files.

```
mount --bind /dev/pts "$CHROOT"/dev/pts
```

Separate instances of devpts shares the same files (if you create or remove a terminal or change its metadata, it's reflected in all instances). However there is evidently some difference under the hood which makes it not work. A bind mount ensures that everything that needs to be synchronized is synchronized since it's the same filesystem and not merely an identical one.

Comment: I just had the opposite problem with a Debian chroot running on QNAP's QTS Linux-based OS.  I'd used a bind mount which caused screen to fail and switching to a devpts mount instead fixed it.

Comment: I tried the bind mount and then mounting -t devpts - both go wrong in some cases.