# How can I fix /dev/pts after mounting it?

Tags: linux, mount, pty

I made the same mistake as in this question: [Debian chroot blocking PTTYs on host](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90285/debian-chroot-blocking-pttys-on-host)

I mounted a "devpts" filesystem inside a chroot, and now urxvt can't create ptys. Oddly enough xterm still can. Remounting /dev/pts doesn't fix the issue.

What can I do to get my system working as normal again without rebooting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @mikeserv I've found out how to revive it.

I have only tested this on Linux 4.0.7, so for much earlier or much later versions it may not work.

```
mount /dev/pts -o remount,gid=5,mode=620
```

Mounting a `devpts` filesystem in a `chroot` without using the `newinstance` option caused it to mount the same "instance" of `/dev/pts`, containing the same ptys. Passing no `gid` argument, according to the man page, causes new ptys to be created with the same gid as the process that spawned it. Apparently this (lack of) mount option affects the entire `devpts` instance, so the original `/dev/pts` is no longer reassigning ptys to the `tty` group. I still don't know why urxvt needs its ptys to be in that group while xterm doesn't.

Some more notes on this:

- It seems normal that `/dev/pts/ptmx` has mode 000 (root:root) while `/dev/ptmx` has mode 666 (root:tty). They do however point to the same block device, so setting `ptmxmode` seems unnecessary but harmless.
- The default `mode` (600) seems to work, but the tty gets created with mode 620 anyway. Something might be changing its mode. When my system boots it passes `mode=620`, overriding the default `mode`, so I've put that in the command line above in the interest of better restoring the default functionality of /dev/pts.
- Don't set `uid`. It will lead you either to security problems or to the same problem of terminals not spawning.
- Adding `newinstance` is optional, but can improve security. With this option, containers can't mount the "real" `/dev/pts` because the host system isn't using it. If this is used, you should ensure `ptmxmode=666` and that `/dev/ptmx` is a symlink to `pts/ptmx`. Mounting a new `devpts` instance over `/dev/pts` may cause strange behaviours in existing terminals (e.g. `gpg` not working), so you should restart those if you use this option.